# PHP calculations with time() and DST issue

Tags: php, time, dst

I'm using a script that insert a date (yyyy-mm-dd) which is X days later than the current date. I add X seconds on the first timestamp to get the second one, at 12:00AM.

Server timezone is UTC -5 and I also set it in my scripts with

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');
```

**We'll set clocks one hour back on NOVEMBER 6 and any mathematical calculations with *time()* seem affected.**
*(When Daylight Saving Time ends in the fall, clocks are set back an hour and Standard Time resumes.)*
At 2:00AM, it'll be 1:00AM on Nov. 6

---

For exemple, the timestamp of date 1: 1320379200 (Friday **4th** November 2011 12:00:00 AM, BEFORE time change)
I want to add 7 days to this date... 1320379200 + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)

Timestamp of the new date is now 1320984000 (Thursday **10th** November 2011 11:00:00 PM, AFTER time change)
but it should be 1320987600 (Friday 11th November 2011 12:00:00 AM)
I miss 3600 seconds, so one hour.

---

So just to make it clear (pseudo-code):

```
$timestampOfStartingDate = 1320379200   
echo timestampToDate($timestampOfStartingDate) // show 2011-11-04 (Friday 4th November 2011 12:00:00 AM)

$newTimestampAfter7days = $timestampOfStartingDate + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)  
echo timestampToDate($newTimestampAfter7days)  // show 2011-11-10 instead of 2011-11-11 (Thursday 10th November 2011 11:00:00 PM instead of Friday 11th November 2011 12:00:00 AM)
```

So I'm missing one hour, which is really probably related to the daylight saving time.

---

The thing is I don't know how to fix that. I don't want to re-do it when we'll re-enter in daylight saving time.

I hope you guys understand what I'm saying, as I'm a little confused.
Also please excuse my english, I'm doing my best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding 7 days, not `x` number of seconds.

```
strtotime("+7 days", $timestampOfStartinDate);
```

Alternatively, use [PHP's DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: Gonna try that right now, I will accept the answer if it works. If yes, I'll consider myself as kinda stupid haha. Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: @Kev, not stupid at all!  I've ran into the exact same problem myself.  Think of it this way... not all days are 24 hours in length.  Really, the best way is to use UTC 0 on the back end, and only display for other time zones for the user.

Comment: it works!! Thanks a lot, I can't accept your answer right now as I've to wait some minutes (because well, you were too fast haha). I should have started with UTC 0 and change it only on display, as you're saying. But now I'm having timestamp stored in UTC -5 with sometimes DST on, sometimes off depending when the timestamp was stored in databaase. I'm really wondering how I could update all that to make them all UTC 0 ..!!

Comment: @Kev, a simple `UPDATE` query on your database can fix this, as long as they are all consistently wrong.  MySQL actually stores things in UTC 0, depending on the type.  (I think a `TIMESTAMP` column does this, and not `DATETIME`, but I don't remember for certain.)